# Windows 8.1 update taking a week to download

Tags: windows, windows-8, updates, windows-8.1

I currently have Windows 8. I started the update for Windows 8.1 a week ago, and it still is only about halfway downloaded. Does anyone else have this issue? Nothing else has ever taken anywhere close to this long to download.

Comment: Is it still increasing? Or is is stuck?

Comment: How fast is your internet connection?

Comment: I had the same issue. The toughest part is windows store apps never tells you whats happening inside and download,speed etc., If you'd good internet connection, would be completed in 3 to 4 hrs.

Comment: upgrade from dial up?

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the Windows 8.1 updated from the Windows store a few days back. It took me  two days and a half to finish.
My internet connection is a 1mbps wireless cellular powered trash that makes turtles look liquid quick and Land Rover look reliable.

I discovered a few things:

- Windows Store itself does not like unreliable connections. If it's stuck loading that Green Windows Store screen (as opposed to the actual store), you have a problem.
- Windows does download files to the local HDD, but I'm not sure at what frequency. In my frustration, more than once had I clicked "Cancel" once or twice, and to try again, only to see that it went back to 0%. In the 10% plus or so, though, cancelling and trying again will resume the download.
- Somewhere past 50% (60% or so, iirc), it actually *stops* downloading - or the UI would like you to believe, and instead starts installing files - and yet it still took a while, even on a Core i7 machine with 8GB of RAM. Something to consider, maybe it just really is slow, offline or online.

How fast and reliable is your connection? Have you tried pinging any websites? Anything else you've downloaded? What percent are you at?

Comment: `Somewhere past 50%, it actually stops downloading...` That only happens with Windows Store apps. Windows 8.1, on the other hand, gives you an "are you sure" message when Windows 8.1 is finished downloading, and only starts installing when you confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Don't close or minimize the windows store app while downloading, If you even minimize the windows store app the download might suspend.
This issue has been addressed in windows 8.1 BTW.

Comment: `The issue has been addressed in Windows 8.1...` But we *are* trying to upgrade to Windows 8.1...

Comment: I knew that, Just told that it is a problem with windows store app itself in windows 8.Did you try upgrading to windows 8.1 by keeping the store app open while downloading?